# password hashing methond using "bcrypt" returns undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, bcrypt

```
import bcrypt from 'bcrypt';

export default class Hash {
 static hashPassword (password: any): string {

   let hashed: string;

    bcrypt.hash(password, 10, function(err, hash) {
      if (err) console.log(err);
      else {
        hashed = hash;
      }

    });
    return hashed;
   }


}
```

> this function returns undefined everytime

Comment: Can you `console.log(bcrypt.hash)` and see what's returned? Also how are you importing bcrypt in your file?

Comment: yes, I am importing bcrypt, I forgot to add it.If I console.log(hash)
from within the scope it returns the hashed password, but when I console.log(hashed) it returns undefined

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the hash function has not finished when you `return hashed`.

You want to handle your hashed password within the callback function itself or handle an asynchronous function as Aluan pointed out.

One way to do that is use a promise

```
export default class Hash {

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        static hashPassword (password: any): string {

       let hashed: string;

        bcrypt.hash(password, 10, function(err, hash) {
          if (err) reject(err);
          else {
            resolve(hash);
          }

        });
       }
    })

}
```

Then when you want to call hash, call it as a promise

```
Hash.then(hashed => {
    console.log(hashed)
}).catch(err => {
    console.log(err)
})
```